# I created a knowledge base in Spanish but the bot responds in English

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

**I created a knowledge base in Spanish** in QnA Maker. And I read in the documentation that this is the way to select the language. Indeed, in my Azure portal I find that it is "Spanish" and cannot be modified. However, both training from the QnA Maker web interface and testing the web chat, **the bot responds in English when it finds no matches**.

I worry about two things:

1. I don't want users who don't understand English to get messages in
   English.
2. Is this affecting the intelligence of my chatbot? That is,
       will not the AI be trying to think in English my texts in Spanish,
       so to speak?

**I would like a solution for "1"** and if anyone knows the answer to my doubts in "2", I would appreciate taking a minute to explain it.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain your question "2" in detail?

Answer (score 0):

If your knowledge base is in Spanish and you are getting the default answer in English when it finds no match, the you can follow the steps below:

- When you query for a question which has no match in the KB, click on the 'Inspect' option right below the question.
- Once you click on the 'Inspect' option, it will expand to a larger window which shows the question and answer tabs. 
  [image]
- On the Answers tab, you can see the default answer in English. Below the Confidence score, you can see an input tab, you can enter the default Spanish answer something along the lines "No se encontró una buena coincidencia en el KB" and enter. The tab will be displayed with the updated answer.

[image]

- Now 'Save and train' the KB and then test it again to see if the changes were updated. It would display the default answer in Spanish.

[image]

Hope this helps!!

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, can you please accept and upvote it so that it helps others? Thanks